# Importing Packages not recognizing methods

Tags: java, class, methods, import, package

So I have 2 packages, one with Sample Classes and one with Simple Coding. Inside the SimpleCode package, I have a class that I need to import from Samples. I use "import Samples.*;" to get all the methods inside the Samples package. But it doesnt recognize it.

Error message : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method lnPrint(String) is undefined for the type AddingMethods

```
at SimpleCode.AddingMethods.main(AddingMethods.java:6)
```

This class is inside the Samples package.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9n2v.png

The class is inside the SimpleCode package, also imported the Samples.*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VxBA.png

Comment: Importing should be done for each class, and in your case, you'll need a static import of the methods from other class.

Comment: You should write your code in the question, not link to screenshots.

Comment: Yeah I cant because I have to post 10 posts beforehand.

Comment: But also, what is the point of importing a package?

Comment: You can import `classes` from a package using wildcard, but for `static` methods, you have no option but to do it at class level.

Answer (score 0):

Call your method as EasyPrinting.inPrint("hello"); in your main method

Answer (score 0):

You aren't utilizing your 'import' correctly. 'Import' does not allow you to freely reference methods in the imported files, it allows you to instantiate classes from the imported files (or use static methods from those files, but you still need to specify the class).

Meaning, you need to say `EasyPrinting.inPrint("hello");` (like RehanZahoor wrote), not just call the method directly.